# remembersLastFocusedIndexPath not working on UICollectionView

Tags: tvos

I have a collection view with a standard horizontal layout. Upon presenting a view controller and then dismissing it, the collection view reset focus back to the first cell, even though the last focused cell was not that one.

I've set

```
self.collectionView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = YES;
```

What's weird is that this only happens when I push a view controller on my navigation controller.

So if I do

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and then dismiss, `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` does not work properly.

However, if I:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then it works as expected.

Any idea why it wouldn't work via a navigation controller?

Comment: Do not waste time on this. This simply does NOT works by now. If you want to keep your selected cell use presentViewController.

Comment: By the way, [self performSegueWithIdentifier:YOUR_SEGUE_ID sender:self] does not works with remembersLastFocusedIndexPath also

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I'm using segues though. `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true` works when I use the "Present Modally" segue kind but not when I use the "Show (e.g. Push)" kind. I've filed a bug report with Apple and will let you know if I hear anything back. Seems like a bug.

P.S. This only occurs when using a `UICollectionView` added to a `UIViewController`. I have no problem when using a `UICollectionViewController`. In my scenario, switching to a `UICollectionViewController` isn't an option though.

Comment: For me `presentViewController:animated:completion:` also does not work :(

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @JeffBowen Any update on the bug report with Apple?

Comment: Haven't heard anything from them @picciano. :(

Comment: @JeffBowen thanks for the great detail info.  it's still completely broken  :/

Comment: @AlejandroLuengo thanks for the great detail info.  it's still completely broken  :/

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me was ensuring that preferredFocusView on the viewController was the collection view:

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    return collectionView
}
```

After this remembersLastFocusedIndexPath seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunately (even in 2022!) this does not fix the Apple bug.

Answer (score 5):

make sure that you don't reloadData() on viewWillAppear of your collectionView or TableView. Otherwise rememberedFocus will be reseted to default (for collection view in my case it was the centre visible cell)

Comment: Doing a reloadData() in viewWillAppear was causing a different item to be focused when coming back to my view controller. Which makes sense, the collection view was reloading cells and the cell getting reused that had focus before was getting focus again after the reload. So, thanks, when I removed the reloadData() in viewWillAppear I then had the proper cell focused.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the system remembers the position. You should probably fix this issue by setting `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` to false.

You could also implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate` method:
`func indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath?`

The documentation tells us:

> The functionality of this delegate method is equivalent to overriding the UICollectionView class’s preferredFocusedView method in the UIFocusEnvironment protocol. If the collection view’s remembersLastFocusedIndexPath method is set to YES, this method defines the index path that gets focused when the collection view is focused for the first time.

But for your issue, setting `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` to false should fix it.

Comment: Nope, this does not fix it.

Comment: This helped point me to how to set the "initial setting" of `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` ... thanks! :)

Comment: By default, `remembersLastFocusedIndexPath` is already set to false.

Comment: This answer appears to have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to implement similar behaviour. Just remember last focused cell in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator)
```

and use this information in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

## For 2022, this is still a severe Apple bug.

#### Simply does not work:

```
 navigationController?.pushViewController(details, animated: false)
```

#### Works perfectly:

```
 present(details, animated: false)
```

#### There are no workarounds, currently:

It seems in the far past some workarounds would make it work. There are no workarounds presently. It is just "utterly broken".

Unfortunately, all you can do is file it under the usual heading "You must be joking, Apple."